# Oracle - How can I improve this PLSQL nested loop to retrieve information?

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursors

I'm coding a complex PL/SQL Procedure to display on screen information about salary details for a determined period from parameter and I've write a first loop for display information about every employee and a second loop for display information about their salaries but both loops don't display information as I can display.

1. The first Cursor retrieve information about employees (emp_id, first name, last name, etc)
2. The second Cursor retrieve information about salaries concepts (federal tax, social security, deductions, etc)

```
FOR i IN (SELECT   a.legajo, a.apellido, a.nombre, 
                   formatear_cuit_cuil(a.cuil) CUIL, a.fecha_alta, 
                   b.numero, b.fecha_liquidacion, b.sueldo_basico,
                   b.codigo_periodo_liq
          FROM     empleados a
          JOIN     liquidaciones b
          ON       (a.legajo = b.legajo_empleado)
          WHERE    b.fecha_liquidacion = v_fecha_liq
          ORDER BY a.apellido, a.nombre ASC)
LOOP
    FOR j IN (SELECT b.descripcion CONCEPTO, a.cantidad,
                     (CASE
                          WHEN c.descripcion LIKE 'HABER' THEN
                               a.importe
                          ELSE
                               NULL
                          END
                     ) haberes,
                     (CASE
                          WHEN c.descripcion = 'ANTICIPO'
                          OR c.descripcion = 'RETENCION' THEN
                               a.importe
                          ELSE
                               NULL
                          END
                     ) retenciones
              FROM   detalles_liquidaciones a
              JOIN   conceptos b
              ON     (a.codigo_concepto = b.codigo)
              JOIN   tipos_conceptos c
              ON     (b.codigo_tipo = c.codigo)
              WHERE  a.numero_liquidacion = i.numero
              AND    c.descripcion IN ('HABER', 'RETENCION', 'ANTICIPO'))
    LOOP        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            'Empleado: ' || LPAD(i.legajo, 4, 0) || ' - ' || 
            UPPER(i.apellido) || ', ' || UPPER(i.nombre));

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUIL: ' || i.cuil);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            RPAD('Concepto', LENGTH(j.concepto), ' ') ||
                    ' Haberes' || ' Retenciones'); 

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(j.concepto);
```

I want to display in console something like that:[image]

But I receive information for the same employee displayed for every salary concepts. Do you have any idea? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you displying data on a screen using dbms_output?

Comment: Thanks for edit my post. Yes, finally I could fixed the problem but now I would like edit my code to display on screen (using DBMS_OUTPUT) as the same way looks in the first screenshot. I think I should add a new question. Thanks for your help William.

Comment: second downvote in turn. i can't see wjat those images are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to place the  dbms_output before the second loop to avoid the employee details printed repeatedly

try this and let me know if it works

```
FOR i IN (SELECT a.legajo, a.apellido, a.nombre, formatear_cuit_cuil(a.cuil) CUIL, 
    a.fecha_alta, b.numero, b.fecha_liquidacion, b.sueldo_basico, b.codigo_periodo_liq 
    FROM empleados a 
    JOIN 
    liquidaciones b 
    ON (a.legajo = b.legajo_empleado) 
    WHERE b.fecha_liquidacion = v_fecha_liq 
    ORDER BY a.apellido, a.nombre ASC) 
    LOOP


                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
                        'Empleado: ' || LPAD(i.legajo, 4, 0) || ' - ' || 
                        UPPER(i.apellido) || ', ' || UPPER(i.nombre));

                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUIL: ' || i.cuil);

                FOR j IN (SELECT b.descripcion CONCEPTO, a.cantidad,
                                 (CASE
                                        WHEN c.descripcion LIKE 'HABER' THEN
                                            a.importe
                                        ELSE
                                            NULL
                                  END
                                  ) haberes,
                                 (CASE
                                        WHEN c.descripcion = 'ANTICIPO'
                                             OR c.descripcion = 'RETENCION' THEN
                                            a.importe
                                        ELSE
                                            NULL
                                        END
                                  ) retenciones
                          FROM   detalles_liquidaciones a
                          JOIN   conceptos b
                          ON    (a.codigo_concepto = b.codigo)
                          JOIN   tipos_conceptos c
                          ON    (b.codigo_tipo = c.codigo)
                          WHERE  a.numero_liquidacion = i.numero
                          AND    c.descripcion IN ('HABER', 'RETENCION', 'ANTICIPO'))
                LOOP


                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
                        RPAD('Concepto', LENGTH(j.concepto), ' ') ||
                        ' Haberes' || ' Retenciones'); 

                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(j.concepto);

        END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
```

Comment: Man you are a GENIUS!!!! It works fine!!! Thanks for your help. I appreciate so much. I chose your answer right!!!